# Breakout style arcade game from 90s

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade, mame

I'm looking for a breakout style game where the paddle was holding by a Chinese character, with red clothes. The character was on the holding above his head the paddle and he was running to not allow the ball to touch the floor. The game was an arcade game. I remember also playing it with MAME long time ago.

Comment: https://www.giantbomb.com/breakout/3030-13049/similar-games/ has a list of games similar to Breakout, sorted by date.

Comment: In what sense are you 'looking for it'?   Do you just want a name, an implementation, or what?

Comment: Thunder & Lightning (1990)

Comment: I think @idspispopd called it: https://www.classic-games.net/thunder-lightning/

Comment: Are arcade games even in our remit?

Comment: Just out of interest, why was my answer converted to a comment? It might not be the correct answer, but I was definitely trying to answer the question. Is some description of the game or a link missing?

Comment: @idspispopd: my guess would be the lack of detail. Linking to a web site or game video, including a description of the matching features, or adding a screen shot (if you have enough karma to add photos) would make it easier for the OP and others to determine if the answer was correct.  ^another-dave: I believe you asked that on meta a couple of weeks ago: https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1218/56

Comment: @fadden -I asked (on meta) about identify-this-game in general, which was judged to be ok provided the question was of good quality.  But we came to no conclusion about arcade games, apart from one opinion (with which I agree) that they're not suitable for 'retrocomputing'.

Comment: @idspispopd Without explaining why the answer might be correct, it's not really an answer. Since the image serves as an "explanation" of sorts, I've undeleted it – though it would be better to have a textual explanation. The mobygames link is unnecessary, though per our "link-only answers" policy, if you think information from the link is relevant, please provide it in your answer (in a blockquote / sourced as necessary). If this happens again, feel free to flag your answer after editing; for irritating technical reasons, only ♦ mods may undelete an answer after it's been converted to comment.

Answer (score 9):

Thunder & Lightning

Published in 1990 on arcade

Definitely a breakout type game

Different characters in the game. The description matches one of those shown in the following screenshot (stereotype Chinese character with a plait, red clothes, holds a paddle over his head).

https://www.mobygames.com/game/26088/thunder-lightning/

[image: Screenshot that shows the chinese character in red clothes with the paddle]